# "Request failed. Tap to retry" when viewing revisions of an answer

Tags: bug, ios-app, revisions-list

When tapping the "Edited … ago" button on [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132415/9357), I consistently get a "Request failed. Tap to retry" error.

It does not appear to be a transient network problem: viewing the revision history of other posts works.

- App Version: 1.5.2
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)